# How to grep line containing some words in certain order?

Tags: grep

I need to find any lines that contains

```
"...where....start_time_local..."
```

using grep. The "..." represent any words. Can you help me on the grep statement?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep "where.*start_time_local" file
```